# Где выполняются подобные действия в Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel5

Мне нужно считать переменную из кэша; если она отсутствует, то сделать несколько запросов к базе данных и записать в кэш; затем - создать глобальную переменную, доступную во всем приложении. Где самое подходящее место для этого? В `Middleware`, вроде как, выполняются другие действия, там не принято выполнять обращения к базе данных и т.д. Сервис-провайдеры? Метод `boot` в `AppServiceProvider`? Что-либо еще?

Comment: Через конфиг, например.

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько, как через конфиг, если нужно делать обращения к базе данных и к кэшу?

Answer (score 2):

AppServiceProvider да можно и в методе boot, но реализацию лучше всю вынеси в отдельный класс, и тут оставь только инстанс тип [как в примере из документации](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/container)

```
$this->app->singleton('HelpSpot\API', function ($app) {
    return new HelpSpot\API($app->make('HttpClient'));
});
```